# What is the common workflow of using cabal for personal project?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Assume I want to creat my own local library called *MyLib*, my workflow is:

```
$ cabal init
# # edit the ".cabal" file, set the "exposed-modules" as "MyLib"
# # edit "MyLib.hs" located in "src"
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install
```

So my question is

- is my workflow an acceptable one, or could it be better?
- now I have a compiled library in  *.cabal-sandbox/lib*, how could I use it or `import MyLib` from my another haskell project? It seems that packages downloaded from hackage through `cabal install` are stored in *~/.cabal*, while my own locally installed package is not there.
- what is the difference between `cabal build` and `cabal install`, it seems that after running `cabal build`, I could already run my lib through `cabal repl`, so what extra jobs does `cabal install` do?

Comment: #1 is acceptable to me; #2 `cabal install /home/me/mylib`

Comment: @josejuan is it so that if I run `cabal install` after `cabal sandbox init`, the package would be installed into current directory, while if no `sandbox` used, it would be intalled into `.cabal` and become a global package?

Comment: yep! if you are into some sandbox then you'll install into that sandbox if not, into global cabal packages :)  (have you seen https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack ? although I recommend learn cabal way anyway)

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `cabal sandbox` so I can't speak much to it.

`cabal build` compiles your source code into your `dist` directory.

`cabal install` takes your compiled source code and sends it to your `~/.cabal` directory, and registers it in your `~/.ghc` directory.  Now you can `import` it into other code just as you would any other library you've installed with cabal.

In my personal projects, I use `cabal configure`, `cabal build`, `cabal repl`, and `cabal install`.  And `configure` is kind of optional.